# Função indefinida mysqli_connect ()

Tags: php, sql

Já tentei mexer no php.ini, reinstalar o php no computador, reinstalar o XAMPP para "ativar o mysqli", mas nada funciona e o meu host online não permite php inferior ao php 7.4.

Erro apresentado:

> Erro fatal : Erro não detectado: chamada para a função indefinida mysqli_connect ().

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
//$usuario = "marcelo";
//$senha = "123";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "dams";

//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname) or die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
```

Comment: "*Já tentei diversas maneiras para ativar o suposto "mysqli"*", quais foram essas maneiras?

Comment: @Woss Mexi no php.ini, alterei algumas coisas reinstalei o php no pc isso off-line. No sistema online não fiz alterações.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Para trabalhar com o PHP 7.0+ tenta alterar a conexão para o seguinte formato:

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario= "user";
$senha = "pass";

// Criar conexão
$conn = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha);

// Verificar se conectou
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Erro: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Conectado com sucesso";
?>
```

Conforme documentação aqui: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php

Ou mudar sua conexão para usar o PDOMysql:

```
<?php

    $usuario = 'user';
    $senha = 'pass';

    try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=servidor;dbname=banco', $usuario, $senha);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Erro: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Como orientado aqui: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-mysql.connection

Comment: tentei, mas mesmo assim o erro persiste

Comment: Edita a pergunta então colocando o seu php.ini... e olha se não tem nenhum erro a mais no log do XAMP também...